# How to understand cause of crash in android ndk (c++)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

How can i understand cause of crash in android ndk program? I tried to use addr2line and ndk-stack tools, but crash log from c++ app isn't meaningful. Below sample of crash log. How can i get crash log as in java program? Thanks in advance.

```
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 0000000c  r1 00000000  r2 00000001  r3 00000004
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 0000000c  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 51625fa0
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 54b71c58  r9 51625f98  sl 51773118  fp 54b71c0c
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 4f0c0fa4  sp 54b71bc0  lr 40263c1b  pc 4025c310  cpsr 20000010
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  5374726174536e4f  d1  61542f6f696c6c63
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  6964654d2f736b61  d3  72656e6e6163536e
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  4c5481d04c548198  d5  4c5482404c548208
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  4c5482b04c548278  d7  4c5483204c5482e8
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 4c5483904c548358  d17 4c712f784c548400
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 4c712fe84c712fb0  d19 4c72ece04c713020
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 4c72e9604c72e928  d21 4c72e9d04c72e998
03-29 12:11:07.890      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 4c72eab04c72ea78  d23 4c72ec384c72ec00
03-29 12:11:07.900      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.900      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 4040000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.900      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 001e001d001c001b  d29 0020001f001e001c
03-29 12:11:07.900      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 003a003a003a003a  d31 0000000000000000
03-29 12:11:07.900      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 28000011
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00012310  /system/lib/libc.so
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00019c17  /system/lib/libc.so (readdir+10)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 00003278  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (iterateDir+172)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 00003248  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (iterateDir+124)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 000031a0  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (Java_com_perm_Stellio_Tasks_MediaScanner_scanNdk+104)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0001f470  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0004e1b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0004ff03  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+174)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 00028920  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 0002d0e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
03-29 12:11:07.910      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 0005f841  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 0005f86b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12  pc 00054c27  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13  pc 00012ff0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14  pc 00012748  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b80  c0000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b84  00001078
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b88  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b8c  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b90  00001080
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b94  4025f69b  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5326)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b98  00001000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71b9c  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71ba0  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71ba4  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71ba8  51625fa0
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bac  4025f9b1  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+56)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bb0  4025f979  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bb4  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bb8  df0027ad
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bbc  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  54b71bc0  00000004
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bc4  0000000c
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bc8  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bcc  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bd0  51625fa0
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bd4  40263c1b  /system/lib/libc.so (readdir+14)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  54b71bd8  00000004
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bdc  4c755c88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71be0  51773108
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71be4  4f0bb27c  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (iterateDir+176)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  54b71be8  51625f98
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bec  5174b548
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bf0  54b71c34  [stack:3321]
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bf4  40261171  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bf8  00000000
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bfc  4f0bb369  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (operator new(unsigned int)+20)
03-29 12:11:07.920      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c00  4c755c88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c04  4f0bb3c7  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+6)
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c08  54b71c34  [stack:3321]
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c0c  4f0bb24c  /data/data/com.perm.Stellio/lib/libtaglib.so (iterateDir+128)
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r7:
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625f80 424e13b8 51625fb0 5333debc 4c755c88  ..NB._bQ..3S.\uL
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625f90 00000000 00000000 1d400005 51625fe0  ..........@.._bQ
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625fa0 5330559a 4c755cc8 5333debc 00000000  .U0S.\uL..3S....
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625fb0 0d1b58ee 00000145 424ccf50 00000001  .X..E...P.LB....
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625fc0 00000000 424e1288 42440710 51626000  ......NB..DB.`bQ
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r8:
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c38 00000000 1d400005 1d500001 5179d3c8  ......@...P...yQ
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c48 50274728 5013f898 54b71c6c 40c3c474  (G'P...Pl..Tt..@
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c58 51625f98 00000001 4245d268 53388257  ._bQ....h.EBW.8S
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c68 00000000 40c6b1bd 51625f98 53388255  .......@._bQU.8S
03-29 12:11:07.930      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c78 4f0bb138 51773118 1d500001 00000000  8..O.1wQ..P.....
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r9:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625f78 53353f66 424ccb88 424e13b8 51625fb0  f?5S..LB..NB._bQ
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625f88 5333debc 4c755c88 00000000 00000000  ..3S.\uL........
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625f98 1d400005 51625fe0 5330559a 4c755cc8  ..@.._bQ.U0S.\uL
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625fa8 5333debc 00000000 0d1b58ee 00000145  ..3S.....X..E...
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51625fb8 424ccf50 00000001 00000000 424e1288  P.LB..........NB
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sl:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 517730f8 21cd6b00 0000b397 00000038 00000453  .k.!....8...S...
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51773108 4d65d188 51625f98 4c755cc8 5007d000  ..eM._bQ.\uL...P
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51773118 0d1b58ee 00000145 54b71da8 00000000  .X..E......T....
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51773128 54b71ddc 00000011 00000000 40c3c600  ...T...........@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 51773138 00000000 00000000 40a87b70 51622300  ........p{.@.#bQ
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near fp:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bec 5174b548 54b71c34 40261171 00000000  H.tQ4..Tq.&@....
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bfc 4f0bb369 4c755c88 4f0bb3c7 54b71c34  i..O.\uL...O4..T
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c0c 4f0bb24c 51625f98 5013f898 54b71c54  L..O._bQ...PT..T
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c1c 04261171 502459e0 502459f0 50245a03  q.&..Y$P.Y$P.Z$P
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71c2c 5174b548 54b71c54 4f0bb1a4 00000000  H.tQT..T...O....
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near ip:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4f0c0f84 4026926d 40269385 40258760 4021739d  m.&@..&@`.%@.s!@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4f0c0f94 40258668 40261179 40263ba9 4026cc41  h.%@y.&@.;&@A.&@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4f0c0fa4 40263c0d 40263c95 40261165 40257e00  .<&@.<&@e.&@.~%@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4f0c0fb4 4025c4b0 4025c8b0 40256ca8 4025cc30  ..%@..%@.l%@0.%@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4f0c0fc4 4025d2e4 4025d4c0 402584c8 4025d414  ..%@..%@..%@..%@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71ba0 00000000 00000000 51625fa0 4025f9b1  ........._bQ..%@
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bb0 4025f979 00000000 df0027ad 00000000  y.%@.....'......
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bc0 00000004 0000000c 00000000 00000000  ................
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71bd0 51625fa0 40263c1b 00000004 4c755c88  ._bQ.<&@.....\uL
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 54b71be0 51773108 4f0bb27c 51625f98 5174b548  .1wQ|..O._bQH.tQ
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4025c2f0 e3a00000 e12fff1e e3822901 eafffffa  ....../..)......
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4025c300 e92d40f8 e2504000 03a00016 08bd80f8  .@-..@P.........
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4025c310 e5942000 e2126903 e2025a02 1a000017  . ...i...Z......
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4025c320 e3853001 e1942f9f e3a01000 e1320005  .0.../........2.
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4025c330 01841f93 e3510000 1afffff9 e1550002  ......Q.......U.
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40263bf8 60052100 60816041 000cf100 eb4af7f8  .!.`A`.`......J.
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40263c08 bd384620 f100b538 4605040c f7f84620   F8.8......F F..
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40263c18 4628ec4c ff9af7ff 46204605 ee44f7f8  L.(F.....F F..D.
03-29 12:11:07.940      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40263c28 bd384628 43f8e92d 460e4690 f7f94604  (F8.-..C.F.F.F..
03-29 12:11:07.950      146-146/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40263c38 2500ff8f 9000f8d0 5000f8c8 ff88f7f9  ...%.......P....
```

Comment: Define what _"meaningful"_ would be to you. Is `libtaglib.so` your library? If so, did you run `addr2line` or `objdump` on (or around) those addresses that you got in the backtrace? If you've built the library with debug info enabled and haven't stripped the library you should be able to map addresses to your original source code.

Comment: Provide more context. The error message looks like it comes from the Stellio Music Player app available on Google Play (see the line which says "Java_com_perm_Stellio_Tasks_MediaScanner_scanNdk"?). Are you trying to access the TagLib shared library of that app in some way?

Comment: Yes i tried use Stellio lib. But what if i have sources? How can i get readable crash log as in java code?

Comment: You have a fairly big clue that this fails when calling readdir(), something that probably doesn't happen that many times in the code, so you can probably find it simply by ruling out the occurrences until you find the one at issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Valgrind? It mainly detects errors relating to memory but can be extended to target other segments too. http://valgrind.org/downloads/